# Error 156 in tSQL sp_executeSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this SQL-Statement and can't find the error

```
Execute sp_executesql 
N' UPDATE tblFI01_Auftraege  
SET @WerteListe  
WHERE Auftrag_id = @Auftrag_ID'
,N'@WerteListe varchar(max), @Auftrag_ID int' 
,@WerteListe= N'Datum_geaendert = GetDate()', @Auftrag_ID = 12;
```

The error says:

> Wrong Syntax near WHERE keyword
>   I've read the description of sp_executesql, but can't find the error.

Any help ?

Comment: You can't parameterise table or column names like that.

Comment: Another case  of _optimistic programming_. You hope that SQL Server will intuit that sometimes you would rather have it interpret the value of a variable as part of a statement, perhaps including more variables, rather than simply treating it as a value. Note that using dynamic SQL gives you a chance to meet [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In the SET clause you should have column = value, in your case you are having just the value of @WerteListe, instead you should have a column from tblFI01_Auftraege = @WerteListe. [TSQL Update syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)

Comment: As I understood the description, the variable @WerteListe should be replaced by "Datum_geander=GetDate()".
So, the UPDATE-Statement should by valid ?

Comment: Re-read the description.
Maybe, I should learn understand english....
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

best is form your dynamic query in a variable, so that you can inspect it before executing

```
select @WerteListe= N'Datum_geaendert = GetDate()'

select @sql = N' UPDATE tblFI01_Auftraege  
SET ' + @WerteListe + '  
WHERE Auftrag_id = @Auftrag_ID'

print @sql  -- print out for your verification

Execute sp_executesql 
             @sql
           , N'Auftrag_ID int'
           , @Auftrag_ID = 12;
```

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for your help.
I misunderstood the description.
With your code it worked perfectly!